# Reload popup with information

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have a table in my popup and I save the values entered by a user to `localStorage`. Here are the snippets.

**popup.html**

```
<table id="main_table">
</table>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**popup.js**

```
function create_row() {
    localStorage["last_session"] = true;
    var table = document.getElementById("main_table");
    var n = table.rows.length;
    var m = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(n);
    if (!localStorage['use_storage']) {
        if (n === 1) {
            localStorage["cells"] = JSON.stringify([{}]);
        }
        else if (n > 1) {
            var cells = JSON.parse(localStorage["cells"]);
            cells.push({});
            localStorage["cells"] = JSON.stringify(cells);
        }
    }
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = n;
    for (j=1; j<m; j++) {
        create_cell(n-1, j, row);
    }
    return row
}

function create_cell(i, j, row){
    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
    if (j == 1) {
        cell.innerHTML = "<input size=10>";
    }
    else {
        cell.innerHTML = "<input size=4>";
    }
    cell.addEventListener("change", function () {
        var cells = JSON.parse(localStorage["cells"]);
        cells[i.toString()][j.toString()] = cell.childNodes[0].value;
        localStorage["cells"] = JSON.stringify(cells);
    })
}

document.getElementById('create_row').onclick = create_row;

// restore a table
if (localStorage["last_session"]) {
    localStorage["use_storage"] = true;
    try {
        var cells = JSON.parse(localStorage["cells"]);
        var n = cells.length;
        var table = document.getElementById("main_table")
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            var row = create_row(true);
            var cell = cells[i]
            for (var key in cell) {
                if (cell.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var col = parseInt(key);
                    var val = cell[key];
                    row.cells[col].childNodes[0].value = val;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Catched error");
        console.log(e);
    }
if (localStorage["results"]) {
        show_results();
    }
    localStorage['use_storage'] = false;
}
```

In my browser it works as it is supposed, that is after refreshing a page popup.html I have the state where I left (number of rows and values are preserved). However, in my chrome extension, after clicking to any area and thus reloading the extension, I have the initial empty table.

How can I preserve the table in this particular case?

Comment: Not enough information, I don't see any problems in this code. How do you populate the table? What's the point of `"use_storage"`? What do you mean by clicking leading to reloading?

Comment: Please, see the edited version. I populate a table with `create_row` function; I use `use_storage` to identify the case when the table should be used from the previous state or not. By reloading application I mean that if I click anywhere anywhere in the browser, my popup disappears, and I open it will be in the initial state. However(!), now when I show results it actually shows results (which is another table). So it's the problem with the main table somehow.

Comment: Solved! Turns out when I stored a bool value in use_storage it converts it to string. Then any non-empty string will evaluate as true. Fancy JS.

Comment: Compelling reason to use `chrome.storage` instead. It automagically does the serialization for you.